Event Study Implementation
I'm trying to get an Event Study Graph to see the effect that replications have on the citation counts of papers.
I have an unbalanced panel dataset that looks something like this:



paper_id
published
citations
year
rep_year
replicated




Gorodnichenco_2017
2017
2
2017
2021
1


Gorodnichenco_2017
2017
20
2018
2021
1


Gorodnichenco_2017
2017
34
2019
2021
1


Gorodnichenco_2017
2017
35
2020
2021
1


Gorodnichenco_2017
2017
61
2021
2021
1


Gorodnichenco_2017
2017
45
2022
2021
1


Gorodnichenco_2017
2017
48
2023
2021
1


Grubb_2015
2015
15
2015
.
0


Grubb_2015
2015
6
2016
.
0


Grubb_2015
2015
10
2017
.
0


Grubb_2015
2015
9
2018
.
0


Grubb_2015
2015
11
2019
.
0


Grubb_2015
2015
11
2020
.
0


Grubb_2015
2015
18
2021
.
0


Grubb_2015
2015
14
2022
.
0


Grubb_2015
2015
12
2023
.
0


Alsan_2018
2018
7
2018
2019
1


Alsan_2018
2018
8
2019
2019
1


Alsan_2018
2018
17
2020
2019
1


Alsan_2018
2018
16
2021
2019
1


Alsan_2018
2018
20
2022
2019
1


Alsan_2018
2018
15
2023
2019
1



Where, replicated is 1 for those papers that were replicated and 0 for papers never replicated. In total, I have 259 observations, 180 papers for "control" and 79 "treated or replicated". The replication year was different for each paper.
I applied this code and got the following graph:
generate timeToTreat = year- rep_year
eventdd citations i.year, timevar(timeToTreat) method(,cluster(P_id)) accum lags(18) leads(18) graph_op(ytitle("Citations per Year"))



As you can see, the leads astart being significant before the event happen.Which could indicate that citations may have started to go up when the replication's working papers started being circulated, or for another reason I'm not capturing in my model.
My problem is, the coefficients seem to be stable over time and the confidence intervals are very big by lag 6. What can I do to improve my model? I think I don't have enough power and that's why I have the issue with CIs. But I don't know if my model is badly implemented or is it because of my data.
I would really appreciate if someone could guide me with this (it's the 1st time I implement this model).
